# CSS cutting off the right side of my webpage.

Tags: html, css

Hey guys not sure what the deal is but when the page is at full screen it all comes into view fine but when the browser is resized down to half or enough to get the top nav bar off the screen it will just cut it off and not animate unless you hover over it. I'm super new to CSS so I'm not really sure what would be causing it because a lot of this code is google-copypasted. So yeah any diagnostics or thoughts on what it might be would be awesome!!

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YkevD/)

Comment: I guess you need to cleanup whole markup and styles

Comment: So you copied this code from an unreferenced source, it's broke, and you want the community to fix it?

Comment: @flem Yes I guess, did you saw the markup? You'll have to sit for an hour to clean it up..

Comment: @Mr.Alien. I did. I started to shift things around, then gave in. Waste of mine and your time.

Comment: @flem Same here, started with a fresh fiddle, picked up the styles and pasted in CSS window and closed my browser tab..

Comment: All of your HTML tags are mixed up. Your `<body>` tag is in the middle of your content, and the end `</head>` tag is too. It looks like parts of the code have been randomly selected and dragged around. (I started to clean up the code, but I think now the best way to go it to recreate a nice, modern HTML5 document.)

Comment: For your next webpage, see the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org). It is the best resource for web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have completely redone your page... so here it is on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VW7yK/1/.

If the browser window is reduced in size, the menu will wrap down (see the Fiddle).

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Site Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
/* Style here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/signupcentral/">Signup Central</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/submit/">Submit</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/contactus/">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/faq/">FAQ</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/logout/">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        Content here.
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div>
            &copy; 2012 HTML Footer Inc. All rights reserved.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
#nav {
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background: #369;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    background: #369;
    border: 1px solid #338;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background .2s;
    -moz-transition: background .2s;
    -webkit-transition: background .2s;
    -o-transition: background .2s;
    -ms-transition: background .2s
}
#nav li:hover {
    background: #36f
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff
}
#content {
    padding: 30px
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center
}
#footer div {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #369;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden` to #navbar2 ul. And also, try looking at stuff yourself. And making stuff yourself. And trying at all.